# Pad above blind or buried via

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-fabrication

For very specific reasons, it would be very neat, to have a pad, for soldering, right above a buried or blind via. E.g. the buried via extends from layer 4-6 and the pad is on the top layer directly above it. Can something like this be fabricated?

Comment: How many layers in your design?

Comment: The Photon in his answer did a good job explaining the issues.  Some questions for you are 1) how cost sensitive is this and 2) how many layers in the PWB?  Also, you need to consult with a PWB manufacturer (or two, or three) and see what their recommendations are.  Most of our boards are 16 layers minimum, up to 40, so multiple lamination steps are needed so the cost of buried vias is not an issue.

Answer (score 3):

Putting a pad above a buried via is not a problem. Depending on your stack-up, making a 4-6 buried via might be relatively expensive.

Buried vias are typically manufactured by doing the drilling operation when the layers are only partially constructed.

For example in an 8 layer stack-up, an inner core is fabricated, with Layer 4 copper on one side and Layer 5 copper on the other. Then buried-vias from 4 to 5 can be drilled before the other layers are built (either by building up pre-preg layers onto the central core, or by building additional cores and then laminating all the cores together with pre-preg in between).

But without doing some extra steps, there isn't likely to be a step in manufacturing when layers 4 through 6 are all laminated together with no other layers present.

For example if you start with a Layer 4 - Layer 5 core (again taking an 8-layer stack-up as an example), and you're doing built-up construction, you'd then laminate on pre-preg layers on each side, and add foils for Layers 3 and 6. So if you drill after that step you'd have Layer 3 to Layer 6 vias, not Layer 4 to Layer 6.

So to design your buried drill schedule you need to consider the details of the stack-up and how it will be constructed, to be sure there will be an opportunity during manufacturing to drill the pairs you want.